# Tensorflow 2.4.1 can't find GPUs

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, conda

I'm trying to run TensorFlow on a Linux machine (ubuntu).
I've created a Conda env and installed the required packages but I think that there's something wrong with my versions:

Updated versions

> <s>cudatoolkit               11.6.0</s> cudatoolkit               11.2.0
>
> cudnn                     8.1.0.77
>
> tensorflow-gpu            2.4.1
>
> python                    3.9.15

Running `nvcc -V` results

> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA
> Corporation Built on Mon_Oct_24_19:12:58_PDT_2022 Cuda compilation
> tools, release 12.0, V12.0.76 Build
> cuda_12.0.r12.0/compiler.31968024_0

and running `python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"` returns an empty list.

Seems that `release 12.0` is the problem here, but I'm not sure and it's not my machine that I'm running on so I don't want to make big changes on my own.

Also, from TensorFlow's site, it seems that `tensorflow-2.4.0` should run with `python 3.6-3.8` and `CUDA 11.0` but the versions I mentioned are the versions that the Conda choose for me.

I know that similar questions have been asked before, but I couldn't find an answer that works for me.

Comment: Can't you make your own virtual env with the version of python required for certain cuda release?

Comment: Python is not a problem. The problem is CUDA. Go through this link: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip and focus on Step 4. You need to select the correct CUDA drivers that will run with TF version of your choice. The bottom line is that you need to match TF version with CUDA version; either upgrade one of them, or downgrade it.

Comment: @eemamedo I've seen it, but it doesn't say which version is compatible with the other

Comment: @RedYoel have you seen this? https://punndeeplearningblog.com/development/tensorflow-cuda-cudnn-compatibility/ . In your config, it seems that the problem is with CUDA ver. 12. The best option would be to create virtual environment, install CUDA 11 and then TF 2.4

Comment: After installing `cudatoolkit 11.2.0` I'm unable to install `tensorflow-gpu`: ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - python=3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally worked for me was to create a new env from scratch using `conda create --name <name> tensorflow-gpu` and then adding the other deps to it. Creating a new env and then installing `tensorflow-gpu` didn't worked.